# start/stop gsm and data connection in android

Tags: android, gsm

I have a small application that writes accelerometer values to a file. I would like the program to switch data and GSM on and off. Is this possible in android? How can i do it in code? Lets say i have a button that when i click it, it switches data and GSM on and another that when i click it switches it off. Please help with sample code that can achieve this.

something like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    if(view.getId() == R.id.startgsm){
        startgsm;
        startdata


    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.button2){
        stopgsm;
        stopdata
    }

}
```

Comment: Your app **cannot** switch on/off the data connection. What it can do is tell the user "Hey, your data connection is off" afterwich it can launch the settings intent for the data connection.

Comment: i have seen apps that switch data on and off. so i believe its possible

Comment: If you have root permissions it is, but in the general case - not